# SPSecurityTrimmedControl isn't executed in the edit mode

Tags: ribbon, suitebar, spsecuritytrimmedcontrol

When I click on Edit Page button the code below doesn't execute, but I have all permissions:

```
<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="ViewPages">
   <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("suiteBar").style.display = "block";
      if (document.getElementById("Ribbon") != null) {
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block"; 
      }
   </script>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Comment: How are you hiding the ribbon? In css then you need to display it in JS?

Comment: Yes it's hidden in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the reason. The problem was in this condition - `if (document.getElementById("Ribbon") != null)` but no in `SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl`. Thank's everyone for your answers.

Comment: Great. Mark it as an answer so others will recognize it

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code after sharepoint UI is loaded:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctions.push(function(){
    document.getElementById("suiteBar").style.display = "block";
      if (document.getElementById("Ribbon") != null) {
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block"; 
      }
});
```

Comment: It's ok, but this code will run for all users. Expected behavior is that for users with Read Only permissions this code shouldn't be executed

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Users with Read Only permissions shouldn't see the ribbon

Comment: From your question I understand that you are not able to run your code in edit mode, right?

Comment: Yes, the code isn't executed in the edit mode. The ribbon should be displayed always for certain category of users

Comment: What I'm trying to say, that you need to replace your code inside `SPSecurityTrimmedControl` with mine